# Arduino sketch will not loop

Tags: arduino

Included in this question is the code I have put together to operate a mushroom greenhouse for hobby growers. I already have an existing and working program but have since upgraded some hardware elements and thought I might trim some fat from my program as well as adding some more sophisticated features. In doing so I have created a program that will compile without error but not perform as it gets stuck in the setup.

The program is being run by an Arduino Mega 2560. Other hardware includes an RTC module, HTU21DF humidity/temp sensor, and a relay module. The device operates lights and fans according to if logic statements from the RTC time and activates a fog pump based off of the readings of the HTU21DF sensor. (more to come with this at a later time).

Please, if somebody could review this code and tell me where the problem is as I would very much like to install this with the more accurate HTU sensor to replace my DHT11 (boo).

---

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Adafruit_HTU21DF.h>
#include <DS3232RTC.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <Wire.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);
Adafruit_HTU21DF htu = Adafruit_HTU21DF();


void setup() {

  pinMode(22, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(23, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(24, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(50, OUTPUT);

   Serial.begin(38400);

 setTime(18,30,50,4,1,16);

 Serial.println("HTU21D-F test");

 if (!htu.begin()) {
   Serial.println("Couldn't find sensor!");
   while (1);
 }
}

void loop() 
{
 digitalClockDisplay();
 fanTimer(); 
 lightTimer();
 humiditySensor();
}

void digitalClockDisplay(){

 // digital clock display of the time
 // lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
 Serial.print("Time ");
 Serial.print(hour());
 printDigits(minute());
 printDigits(second());
 Serial.println();
}

void printDigits(int digits){
 // utility function for digital clock display: prints preceding colon and leading 0
 Serial.print(":");
 if(digits < 10)
 Serial.print('0');
 Serial.print(digits);
} 

void fanTimer(){
if (
    ( minute() >= 0 && minute() < 4)
    //|| ( minute() >= 12 && minute() < 14)
    || ( minute() >= 20 && minute() < 24)
    //|| ( minute() >= 32 && minute() < 34)
    || ( minute() >= 40 && minute() < 44))
    //|| ( minute() >= 52 && minute() < 54))
{
  digitalWrite ( 23, LOW );
}
else
{
  digitalWrite ( 23, HIGH );
}    
}

void lightTimer(){
if ( hour() >= 6 && hour() < 18)
{
digitalWrite ( 22, LOW );
}
else
{
  digitalWrite ( 22, HIGH);
}
}

void humiditySensor() {
 float h = htu.readHumidity();

  // lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  Serial.print( "Hum: "); 
  Serial.println(htu.readHumidity());
  delay(500);


  if (h <= 95)
  {
    digitalWrite (50, HIGH);
  }
  else 
  {
    digitalWrite (50, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: does it print "Couldn't find sensor!"?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the only place where your code can get *stuck* in the setup is in the humidity sensor initialization procedure `htu.begin()` where it fails to connect to the sensor or the sensor's response isn't as expected.
You should ensure that it is connected correctly including power pins and the two data lines.

However, you should also get a message in serial output stating just that: "Couldn't find sensor!"

Further information from your side would be needed e.g.:

- According to what information you concluded that "it gets stuck in the setup"?
- What do you get from the serial output?
- What hardware elements did you upgrade and did you test them individually?

To make it easier to troubleshoot I can recommend to test every major component one by one - for example run the example sketch that came bundled with the HTU21D-F sensor's library and see if that works.

Comment: Each component was tested individually and the only hardware to change was the humidity sensor from a DHT11 to the HTU21DF. In the example sketch, and "test" program I wrote the sensor worked just fine.

Comment: I suppose saying it is getting "stuck in the setup" was a poor way of wording things. It clearly makes it past setup because the Serial monitor will print 2 lines, however these 2 lines only print one time and that is it. The initial set time will print, and "HTU21D-F Test". That is it. it will not loop back through and print the updated time or the value of humidity.

Comment: I believe it is something in the HTU test because if I comment everything having to do with the Humidity sensor out, the time will run fine and the loop works.

Answer (score 0):

This is beyond embarrassing but after reviewing my wiring (I can not believe I did this) I had the +/- lines switched on the breadboard. I swapped the wires, no more problems.... I swear, wiring is always the issue with me!!!